# Multiple rows in freemarker and page break pdf

Tags: xslt, freemarker, xsl-fo

Suppose you have the following below. How I can wrap those in order to produce a page break if the rows don't fit on a page ?

```
<fo:table-body start-indent="0pt">
 #loop here
   <fo:table-row>
   </fo:table-row>

   <fo:table-row>
   </fo:table-row>

   <fo:table-row>
   </fo:table-row>


 # loop ends here
</fo:table-body>
```

Comment: It should break unless you have some keep set like on the table itself or a containing block

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<fo:table-body start-indent="0pt">
```

to:

```
<fo:table-body start-indent="0pt" keep-together.within-page="always">
```

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#keep-together

Comment: I think the post says he wants a page break

Comment: Hi Tony. The problem is that its a list of data. For each item in the loop there should be a page break. If I use keep-together.within-page in say 100 items coming in. It will be 4 * 100 rows. It will try to squeeze all of it on one page.

Comment: Sorry, I read it as wanting a page break before the table.  As @kevin-brown said, by default, the table should break if it won't all fit on one page.  What have you tried that does not work?